# Amazon EC2 Instance connectivity

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have created an ec2 instance and followed all steps according to AWS documentation, But I am unable to connect to database from the php files in html folder. Below is the error

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1130): Host
>   'ip-172-31-28-115.us-west-2.compute.internal' is not allowed to
>   connect to this MySQL server in /var/www/html/test/test.php on line 11
>   Unable to connect to MySQL

The Php files are not getting connected to the database that is created on instance.

*Note:* I also tried creating new user and granted privileges to the new user but no luck!

It would be great if you can assist us through problem, since we have already spent lot of time experimenting on this.

Comment: You should install Linux on your laptop or desktop to become familiar with it. It would be cheaper and easier than learning Linux remotely on an AWS instance.

Answer (score 4):

Things to check for MySQL connection:

--/etc/my.cnf to ensure that listening on the right port(s) ip(s). 3306 default.
--Open port 3306 in AWS to ensure that client can access 
--Grant privs on database to user that is connecting. 
--Examine mysql logs and apache error logs for errors.

Comment: Agree with @George J. Nassef Jr. - definitely check the Security Group of your instance to make sure you are allowing the MySQL port through.

Answer (score 3):

can you try running this? I think it has to do with permissions.

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;